# Foreach in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select some news excluded the first 4 and I got a error
Invalid argument supplied for foreach:
Model:

```
public function get_all_news_home()
{
    $exclude = array();
    $this->load->database();
    $last_news_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE Type = 1 AND Ready='Y' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 4");
    $last_news = $this->db->query($last_news_query);
    $last_news = ($last_news->num_rows()) ? $last_news->result_array() : NULL;
    foreach ($last_news as $ln) 
    {
        array_push($exclude,array('id' => $ln['ID']));
    }

    $newsIds = implode(',', array_values($exclude));


    $all_news = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE News.Ready = 'Y' AND News.ID NOT IN ('$newsIds') ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 12");

    if($all_news->num_rows())
    {
        $all_news = $all_news->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        $all_news = NULL;
    }
    return $all_news;
}
```

Controller:`$this->data["all_news"] = &$this->site_news->get_all_news_home();`

Comment: check query manually ur getting results or not..

Comment: That is a terrible thing you do. You can do this with one query very easily. Did you ever try this with one query?

Comment: Now,but how to do his with one query?If you say with the Limit(I'm sorry not effective)

Comment: your error is clear, ur assigning NULL value to $last_news if no result and ur trying to pass that one to foreach make correct that one first. then if need query optimization do it.

Comment: Can you please try with the following query:  SELECT * FROM News WHERE News.Ready = 'Y' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 4,12;

Comment: I got an error Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Comment: At what line you are getting this `preg_match()` error?

Answer (score 0):

change this. you should check for null condition before passing it to foreach.

```
public function get_all_news_home()
{
    $exclude = array();
    $this->load->database();
    $last_news_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE Type = 1 AND Ready='Y' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 4");
    $last_news = $this->db->query($last_news_query);
    $last_news = ($last_news->num_rows()) ? $last_news->result_array() : NULL;
    $all_news = NULL;
    if($last_news!=NULL){
       foreach ($last_news as $ln) 
       {
          array_push($exclude,array('id' => $ln['ID']));
       }

       $newsIds = implode(',', array_values($exclude));
       $all_news = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE News.Ready = 'Y' AND News.ID NOT IN ('$newsIds') ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 12");

       if($all_news->num_rows())
       {
          $all_news = $all_news->result_array();
       }
    }
    return $all_news;
}
```

Comment: Palani,now another error : Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Answer (score 0):

```
$exclude = array();
$this->load->database();
$last_news = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE Type = 1 AND Ready='Y' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 4");

//$last_news = $this->db->query($last_news_query);
//remove this line you are re-executing the query.

$last_news = ($last_news->num_rows()) ? $last_news->result_array() : NULL;

//before foreach add if condition 
if (!is_null($last_news)) {
    //add your code
}
```

Adding `if` condition before `foreach` is always a good practice. I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this simple function should work nicely for you. Please use this simple function and let us know what happened.

```
public function get_all_news_home()
{
    $this->load->database();

    $all_news = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE Type = 1 AND Ready = 'Y' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 4, 12");

    if($all_news->num_rows())
    {
        $all_news = $all_news->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        $all_news = NULL;
    }
    return $all_news;
}
```